# Ember.Computed is not a function

Tags: ember.js, chart.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to setup simple application with Ember using ember-chart:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-chart

I have my charts.hbs file:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        {{#toggle-section}}
            <div class="chart-container">
                {{ember-chart type=CHARTTYPE data=CHARTDATA options=CHARTOPTIONS width=CHARTWIDTH height=CHARTHEIGHT}}
            </div>
        {{/toggle-section}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my charts.js controller with sample from documentation of Chart.js:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import Ember from "ember";

export default Controller.extend({
    CHARTTYPE: 'bar',
    CHARTDATA: Ember.Computed('', function () {
        return {
            labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        }
    }),
    CHARTOPTIONS: Ember.Computed('', function () {
        return {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }),
    CHARTWIDTH: 500,
    CHARTHEIGHT: 500,
});
```

In index.js route i have redirection to charts route:

```
beforeModel() {
    this.replaceWith('charts');
}
```

When I am trying to open my `localhost:4200` after `ember s` it gives me an error in console:

`router.js:927 Error while processing route: index Ember.Computed is not a function TypeError: Ember.Computed is not a function`

I tried to search for an answer but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is lowercase: `Ember.computed`

It would also be better to use this import:

```
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
```

to avoid having to bring in all of the Ember framework just to access the computed function.